# how to trace nodejs express serving static files

Tags: node.js, express

I need to trace all "static" files served by nodejs express

I use
app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, '/public' ) ) ) ;

Can it be done ?

I'd like to use simple "console.log( "static serving" + filename ) ;

Answer (score 1):

You can use express to write middleware for the route `/public`. Something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const PORT = 3000;

app.use('/public', (req, res, next) => {
    const { url, path: routePath }  = req;
    console.log(url);
    // or
    console.log(routePath);
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app is running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Max : great and complete solution. The magic word here is "next()" - can you provide a pointer to good documentation on this function ?

Comment: Sorry, Max - this code does serve files from "/public" directory but does trace NOTHING, none, nop, niente, zero.

Comment: @Sebastia.Net next is documented here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: @Sebastia.Net this is very minimal. The point is, in that middleware function you can do whatever you want to "trace" requests to the `/public` route. You weren't very clear on "tracing." Your question asked to "simply" `console.log`

Comment: @Sebastia.Net it's a template literal. Rather than concatenating a variable into a string, javascript has template literals for this purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks, Max - as you can see I changed your apostrophes (`) into spanish keybord ones (') and your line stopped working so I was coplaining

Comment: Anyway, in my node and express your "console.log(routePath);" does not get control, that branch is never activated, dont know why

Comment: @Sebastia.Net you might have to put the middleware route above the `express.static` route. The `express.static` is probably resolving the request before it hits the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom middleware which checks if a request is pointing on some static asset by looking on `request.path`. For example:

```
module.exports = (request, response, next) => {

    const {method, path} = request;
    if (method.toLowerCase() === 'get' && path.startsWith('/public'))
        console.log('static serving', path);

    next();
};
```

Does it help?

Comment: Sebastian : I dont see where you use "request.path"

Comment: It's here: `const {method, path} = request;` - I used object destructuring. It's equivalent to `const method = request.method, path = request.path;`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got some code that logs ALL requests :

```
const express = require('express') ;
const path    = require('path') ;
const app     = express() ;

const PORT = 3000 ;

var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {

  const { url, path: routePath }  = req ;
  console.log( 'my LOGGER - URL (' + url + '), PATH (' + routePath + ').' ) ;

  next() ;
}

app.use(myLogger) ;

app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, '/public') ) ) ;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log( 'app is running on port {'+PORT+'}.' ) ;
} ) ;
```

Even shorter :

```
const express = require('express') ;
const path    = require('path') ;
const app     = express() ;

const PORT = 3000 ;

app.use( function ( req, res, next ) {
  console.log( '### common TimeStamp:', Date.now() ) ;
  next() ;
} ) ; // timestamp all

app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, '/public') ) ) ;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log( 'app is running on port {'+PORT+'}.' ) ;
} ) ;
```

Ciao.

Answer (score 0):

This code works :

```
const express = require('express') ;
const path    = require('path') ;
const app     = express() ;
const PORT = 3000 ;

app.use( function ( req, res, next ) {
    const { url, path: routePath }  = req ;
    console.log( '### common TimeStamp:', Date.now(), ' - my LOGGER - URL (' + url + '), PATH (' + routePath + ').' ) ;
    next() ;
} ) ; // timestamp all

app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, '/public' ) ) ) ;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log( `app is running on port ${PORT}.` ) ;
} ) ;
```

This code dont :

```
const express = require('express') ;
const path    = require('path') ;
const app     = express() ;
const PORT = 3000 ;

app.use( '/public', function ( req, res, next ) {
    const { url, path: routePath }  = req ;
    console.log( '### common TimeStamp:', Date.now(), ' - my LOGGER - URL (' + url + '), PATH (' + routePath + ').' ) ;
    next() ;
} ) ; // timestamp all

app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, '/public' ) ) ) ;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log( `app is running on port ${PORT}.` ) ;
} ) ;
```

Why ? I just dont know.

As you can see, the only difference is "app.use" has "/public" or not ...

It seems to me "express.static" takes it all ...